# Solving method for fractions having Prime numbers as Denominator.

Tags: contest-math, problem-solving, puzzle

I have a question , like

> $30 = 1.18x$ , and $30 = 0.82 y$ , find $x+y$.

when solving, $x=1500/59$, $y=1500/41$. Since the denominator is involving prime numbers I was wondering is there any method or some logic is there to solve this question under 30 seconds.?

---

The actual question goes like this :

**A man sold two gifts at $\$30$ each. On one gift he gained $18\%$ and on the other gift he lost $18\%$. What is his overall gain/loss(in $)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from an4s's answer:

$$\frac{60}{1 - 0.18^2} = \frac{60}{1 - \left(\frac{9}{50} \right)^2} = \frac{60}{1 - \frac{81}{2500}} = \frac{60}{\frac{2500 - 81}{2500}} = \frac{60 \cdot 2500}{2500 - 81} = \frac{150 \ 000}{2419}.$$

Then using the options in the multiple-choice question:

$$\frac{150 \ 000}{2500} < \frac{150 \ 000}{2419} < \frac{150 \ 000}{2400}$$
$$\frac{150}{25} < \frac{150 \ 000}{2419} < \frac{500}{8}$$
$$60 < \frac{150 \ 000}{2419} < 62.5$$

Since the gifts are between $60$ and $62.5$ dollars, he has therefore made a *loss*. Then the answer must be between options $B$ and $C$. However, since his loss is strictly less than $60 - 62.5 = -2.5$ dollars, then the answer is option $B$.

Comment: the answer I am expecting the decimal form . 62.009. Kindly consider solving this fraction also  .

Comment: Why would you need a decimal form? How many digits of the calculation do you need? I can't read your mind, so I need more information about the background of this problem before I can help you. Here is [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: I have updated the question . please have a look at it.

Comment: yes . the 30 second tag I put because I took this question from a MCQ paper, where one question can have max 1 min.

Comment: In this case, what are the options (ABCD)? You can usually rule out a few of the options as I'm sure they don't expect you to do the long division.

Comment: Options :  (a) Gain of $1.75$,  (b) Loss of $2.00$, (c) Loss of $2.50$, (d) Gain of $2.00$

Comment: @TobyMak I think you are missing a $0$. It should be $150000$ in the numerator.

Comment: Yep, thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Lawliet Notice that you can round down the denominator to $2400$. Now, $\dfrac{150000}{2400} = 62.5$. The man sold the items for $\$60$ and, therefore, lost $\$2.50$.

Comment: Actually, the answer is option $D$. Using a calculator, $\frac{150 \ 000}{2419}$ is almost exactly $62$ dollars.

Comment: @TobyMak Oh, yes. You are correct. $\dfrac{150000}{2500} = 60 < \dfrac{150000}{2419} < \dfrac{150000}{2400} = 62.5$. So, _technically_ the answer should be somewhere between $\$0$ and $\$2.5$.

Comment: @TobyMak are you sure it's D, though? $x + y$ is the _actual_ price of the items. So if the man sold the items for $\$60$, then he lost $\$(x + y - 60)$, no?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: sold for : $60$, Bought for $62$ So loss is $62-60 = 2 $ Correct.??

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: But still, I am not satisfied with the inequality shown by @an4, as the answer is coming to 62.00, can we do some manipulation to re write the primes coming in the denominator .??

Comment: not that , $60<\frac{150000}{2419}<\frac{150000}{2400}$. this one . I am sorry if inequality is a wrong word to be used .

Comment: This works because all three fractions have the same numerator. For example, if I cut a cake into $3$ pieces, and I cut the same cake into $5$ pieces, one slice of cake in the cake with $5$ pieces is clearly smaller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111045/discussion-between-toby-mak-and-lawliet).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\begin{align}30 &= 1.18x \implies x = \dfrac{30}{1.18} \\ 30 &= 0.82y \implies y = \dfrac{30}{0.82} \end{align}$$

Therefore, $$x + y = \dfrac{30}{1.18} + \dfrac{30}{0.82} = \dfrac{30(1.18 + 0.82)}{1.18\cdot 0.82}$$

Now, notice that

$$\begin{align}1.18&\equiv1 + 0.18\\ 0.82&\equiv 1 - 0.18\end{align}$$

and $$(a + b)(a - b) = (a^2 - b^2).$$

Comment: But now also the division is involved. ! that too prime numbers . How to solve it any idea apart from conventional division .? Also for my knowledge may I know why you downvoted my question .?

Comment: So we got $\frac{60}{1-0.0324}$, what's next?

Comment: @Lawliet The best way to train for a competition is never to focus on speed first, but rather first work on understanding the concepts fully, then worry about speed. I'm assuming that your problem is from a contest. If so, please put the name of the competition and what concepts it tests.

Comment: its not with fast, but my doubt is that the denominators are prime numbers and one division is also involved , so any mathematical identities are there to solve such a problem .

Comment: Or some way I can manipulate the prime numbers so that the division can be done easily .?

Comment: I'm writing an answer right now, so just hold on for a second.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin thanks for pointing that out. I am expecting that the OP finds it simpler to perform the resulting long division. Although, I do realize now that my answer might not be _exactly_ answering what was asked, and I am willing to delete this answer if the OP does not find it useful _at all_.

Comment: Please don't. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3769511) shows how to end yours. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If that was the original question then: $30=1.18x$ and $30=0.82y$ what is $x+y$--- is not the right question.  The right question is what is $0.18x - 0.18y$.

If $g$ is $0.18X$ then gain on the first gift and $l = 0.18Y$ the loss on the second gift then:

$X +g = X + 0.18X  = 30$ so $X = \frac {30}{1.18}$ and $g=0.18\frac {30}{1.18}$

And $Y - l = Y-0.18X = 30$ so $Y=\frac {30}{0.82}$ and we need $g-l= 0.18\cdot 30 \cdot (\frac 1{1.18} -\frac 1{0.82})=$

$0.18\cdot 30\cdot (\frac {1-0.18}{(1+0.18)(1-0.18)}- \frac {1+0.18}{(1+0.18)(1-0.18)})=0.18\cdot 30\cdot(\frac {-2\cdot 0.18}{1-0.18^2})=$

$-60\cdot \frac {0.18^2}{1-0.18^2}=$

$-60\cdot \frac {18^2}{10000-18^2}=$

$-60\cdot \frac {9^2}{2500-9^2}=$

$-60\cdot \frac {81}{2419}=$

$-\frac {4860}{2419} \approx 2.01$.

..... or we could have do this from the start.

> $X=\frac {30}{1.18} \approx 25.43$ so he made $30-25.43 = 4.57$

> $Y = \frac {30}{0.82} \approx 36.59$ so he lost $36.59-30 = 6.59$ cents

> So his loss was $-6.59 + 4.57 = -2.02$ (a one cent rounding error).

Is there a way to solve this 30 seconds by evaluating $\frac {30}{1.18} = {1500}{59}$ and $\frac {30}{0.82} = \frac {1500}{41}$?

I.e. $(\frac {1500}{59}-\frac {1500}{41}) = 1500\frac {41-59}{59*41}= 1500\frac {-18}{(50+9)(50-9)}= -18*1500*\frac 1{2500-81}$ and

.... I dunno....Seems about the same amount of work as my first method.  The highlighted method is probably the fastest and easiest.